# How to avoid printing the ASCII value of '\n' in a while loop?

Tags: c

My task is to get an input, print out the character and the ASCII value, and to present them each 8 for 1 line. For every input I'm typing I'm getting also the value of the newline character and I don't want to print it.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{       
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    printf("please type an input:\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')          
    {
        ++count;           
        printf("%c=%d ", ch, ch);
        if (count%8 == 0) printf("\n");
    }        
}
```

Comment: `if (ch != '\n') printf("%c = %d ", ch, ch);`?  And only increment the `count` when the character is not a newline?  Your question is ill-defined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another `getchar()` right after reading the first one:

```
  while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
  {
       getchar();  // To eat the newline character
       // Rest of code
  }
```

---

Or you can use scanf() and rewrite the loop equivalently:

```
   while (scanf(" %c", &ch)==1)
    {
        if(ch != '#')
        {
          ++count;
          printf("%c=%d ", ch, ch);
          if (count%8 == 0)
             printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but this effecting the 8 pairs for a line...how do i keep that rule? @KingsIndian

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 8 pairs. Think this way: Each time you press `Enter` key, you have to consume the newline. So use a getchar() there.

Comment: Oh ok, so i can just add 'if (ch == '\n') break; thanks! @KingsIndian

Comment: Is it safe to pass a `char` to `printf` after specifying `%d` in the format? Shouldn't the `hh` length specifier be used? Does it work in practice because of some padding?

Comment: @MaciejHehl The `char` argument to printf() is promoted to `int` as per *default argument promotions*. So yes, it's safe and here's no padding or anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()    
{       
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    printf("please type an input:\n");
    while (1) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '#') break;
        if (ch == '\n') continue;         

        printf("%c=%d ", ch, ch);
        if (!(++count%8)) printf("\n");
    }        
}
```